# How to make a sdk jar like admob

Tags: android, jar, project, package

Greetings,

I've created an Hoptoad for Android utility tool as an Android Library Project. Is there a way that I can package it into a jar like the admob-sdk-android.jar?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the java command line or when using Eclipse you can simply export to JAR.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html

Comment: mentioned link is broken

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to take the standard build and clean the irrelevant parts:

1 create a dummy android project
2 add your code 
3 compile it with ant, using the default build.xml file
4 now that you are sure that everything compiles fine, override some targets in build.xml:

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <delete dir="${out.absolute.dir}/classes/com/dummyprojectfiles" verbose="${verbose}" />
</target>
 <target name="-package-release" depends="-dex">
</target>
<target name="release"
            depends="set-release-mode, -release-obfuscation-check, -package-release, -release-prompt-for-password, -release-nosign"
            if="has.keystore"
            description="Builds the application.">
    <signjar
            jar="${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/obfuscated.jar"
            signedjar="${out.unaligned.file}"
            keystore="${key.store}"
            storepass="${key.store.password}"
            alias="${key.alias}"
            keypass="${key.alias.password}"
            verbose="${verbose}" />

    <!-- Zip aligns the APK -->
    <zipalign-helper in.package="${out.unaligned.file}"  out.package="${out.release.file}" />
    <echo>Release Package: ${out.release.file}</echo>
</target>
```